# OpenLayers Proxyhost is not working properly

Tags: proxy, openlayers, geoserver

As it is said in http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost I did put the proxy.cgi file in server where documentation is saying and It is showing the openlayer page while go to "http://mydomain.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi". That means proxy set up is correctly done for the server. but while I try at my script use this proxy it is not working. 
I put "`OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";`" in my script. so that the proxy can be used.

My code is here which is not working.

```
ainSelect = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                    url: 'http://ec2-23-22-12-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/KCRE/wms',
                    title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                    layers: [lyrParcels],
                    queryVisible: true
                });
ainSelect.infoFormat = 'application/vnd.ogc.gml';
                ainSelect.events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, pickAINid);
                map.addControl(ainSelect);
                ainSelect.activate();
```

And pickAINid function is:

```
function pickAINid(e) {
            //alert(e.features.length);
            if (e.features && e.features.length) {

                var val = e.features[0].attributes.ain;
                alert(val);
                //document.getElementById('roadId').value = val;
            }
        }
```

So it should alert me the AIN number while i click on the map. As far as I've got it is getting e.features.length = 0. that means WMSGetFeatureInfo is not working correctly.

Please see that I've used the layers:[lyrParcels] I created that layer before which code i haven't give here.

Another point. this code is just working fine while I run this code from my local.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Is it on this "`OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";`" line?

Thanks in advance.

regards
Mahbubul Haque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the proxy.cgi there is a list of allowed host at the top of the file ( like below).

```
allowedHosts = ['www.openlayers.org', 'openlayers.org', 
            'labs.metacarta.com', 'world.freemap.in', 
            'prototype.openmnnd.org', 'geo.openplans.org',
            'sigma.openplans.org', 'demo.opengeo.org',
            'www.openstreetmap.org', 'sample.azavea.com',
            'v2.suite.opengeo.org', 'v-swe.uni-muenster.de:8080', 
            'vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org', 'www.openrouteservice.org']
```

If you havent you need to add the domain(and port in your case as its not 80) of the server you are contacting, in this case :

```
ec2-23-22-12-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
```

If this is not the source of the problem could you provide some more info from a javascript debugger such as firebug showing any errors or warning when you try to make the request through the proxy.

**UPDATE**

Its seems from testing your proxy on your server that you have an issue connection to port 8080 from inside your network.

this can be tested by trying the urls

```
http://kleincom.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http://v-swe.uni-muenster.de:8080
```

and

```
http://kleincom.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http://labs.metacarta.com
```

The metacarta url works fine but the muenster url fails with a timeout issue. I would have a look at your out going firewall setting or similar.

Comment: I've already added the domain in allowedHosts variable in cgi script. and with 8080 port I've added http://ec2-23-22-12-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080

Comment: ok then could you add some information from a javascript debugger as to what is actually happeneing when you request info?

Comment: i'm not going to debug it for you! just post any relevant debug output in your question above

Comment: when I click on the map it sends XMLHttpRequest which url is: http://kleincom.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=

Comment: when I click on the map it sends XMLHttpRequest which url is: "http://kleincom.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-23-22-12-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com%3A8080%2Fgeoserver...." It sends the request and response is: "Some unexpected error occurred. Error text was: <urlopen error (110, 'Connection timed out')>"  But if I put the url "http://ec2-23-22-12-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/KCRE/wms?LAYERS=..." on browser I get the gml file downloaded which contains the expected result.